# C-Compiler says "Cannot convert char * to char" while assigning a string to a char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

The following Code is part of a C project. The project has a Header File in which two structs are defined and declared.
Im german so my text is, but thats only the output and the names of the variables. 
My problem is: In the case lines a string has to be written in a char array. It gives me the error "Cannot convert char* to char". I put a arrow there.
I tried to solve this by using gets, puts or something like that, and I also couldnt find a answer in the internet that helped.
Maybe you can help me?

```
#if !defined(krftst_cpp)
#define krftst_cpp
#include "typ1.h"

krftst()
{
 int antww;
 FILE *datei;

  if((datei = fopen("datei.dat", "r+b")) == NULL)
 {
  fprintf(stderr, "Konnte Datei nicht öffnen");
  return 1;
 }

 printf("   Folgende Kraftstoffe stehen zur Wahl:\n");
 printf("      -1 Super\n");
 printf("      -2 E10\n");
 printf("      -3 Diesel\n");
 printf("      -4 Biodiesel\n");
 printf("      -5 Gas\n\n");
 printf("   Sollten sie ein Elektroauto fahren, geben sie bitte 6 ein.\n");
 printf("   Bei einem Hybridauto normal den Kraftstoff angeben.\n);
 scanf("%d",&antww);

 switch(antww)
 {
  case 1:
         Werte.krftst[20]= "Super";  <--
         break;

  case 2:
         Werte.krftst[20]= "E10";  <--
         break;

  case 3:
         Werte.krftst[20]= "Diesel";  <--
         break;

  case 4:
         Werte.krftst[20]= "Biodiesel";  <--
         break;

  case 5:
         Werte.krftst[20]= "Gas";  <--
         break;

  case 6:
         Werte.krftst[20]="Elektro";  <--
         printf("Geben sie bei Kraftstoffverbrauch statt 'l' 'W' ein, um in Wattt zu rechnen.");
         break;

  default:
   printf("Bitte geben sie nur die Zahlen 1 bis 6 ein!");

 }

}

#endif
```

The declaration of werte:

```
struct Daten { 
    char start[20]; 
    char ziel[20]; 
    int km; 
    int vrbr; 
    char dnstf; 
    char name[30]; 
    char knzchn[10]; 
    char krftst[20]; 
    char einh; 
    char dtm[12]; 
};
```

Comment: Where did you define `Werte`?  More specifically, what is the type of `Werte.krftst`?

Comment: Werte.krftst[20] will store a charater but by using Werte.krftst[20]= "Super" you are assiging a pointer.

Comment: What is `Werte.krftst`? Do you want to use `strncpy`?

Comment: stackoverflow is an international community and according to the rules we use English for primary language. Please avoid posting questions with significant part in another language. Also in this case only a small portion of the code is relevant to the question being asked(and a significant part of it is **not** included in your post). We need to know **what** is `Werte` while  we don't need 20 lines of logging.

Comment: Im so sorry, this is the first time im using this site...Im working on this project for weeks now and im very frustrated...

Comment: Don't feel bad. No-one's telling you off, just giving you guidance on how things work here. It takes time to get used to a new site and how it works. There are some useful guides in the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) that should help you out though. This one on [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might particularly be of interest to you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a string to an array during initialization, but after that you should use `strcpy` to "assign" strings.

```
char x[50] = "hello";  // Initializtaion. 

x = "goodbye";      // Not ok. Compile error
x[0] = "goodbye";   // Not ok. Compile error

strcpy(x, "goodbye");       // OK
strcpy(&x[10], "goodbye");  // OK, goodbye\0 will be placed 10 characters into x.
```

You should use:

```
strcpy(Werte.krftst, "Super");
```

If you use `strcpy` you should

```
#include <string.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the string in an array after the delaration of an array,use the strcpy function to copy the stirng in array.

```
 Werte.krftst[20]= "Super"
```

should be

```
strcpy(Werte.krftst,"supper");
```

Comment: This is the file "typ1.h":

Comment: check your file typ1.h. what is krftst?

Comment: #if !defined(typ1_h)
#define typ1_h
struct Daten
 {
 char start[20];
 char ziel[20];
 int km;
 int vrbr;
 char dnstf;
 char name[30];
 char knzchn[10];
 char krftst[20];
 char einh;
 char dtm[12];
 };                        

struct Rechn
 {
 float vrbrPRO;
 float vrbrG;
 float kmG;
 float vrbrEinz;
 float vrbrPROG;
 };

 struct Rechn Ergebn;

 struct Daten Werte;

 extern char Dtpfad;
 int control;
 #endif dam* i will write this in a answer

Comment: use strcpy(krftst,"Super")

Comment: That was just an example.

Comment: @DevSolar it's possible that someone wants to store the pointer to the character in an array. But you have declared char array. That's why i assumed that, this may be a scenario.

Comment: @DevSolar in krftst, we can store 50 base addresses of string starting from index 0 to index 49. krftst[49]="Super". If i am wrong, tell me how i am thinking wrong.

Comment: @DevSolar, thanks. I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A char array can be initialized by a string literal only at the point of declaration.

This works:

```
char foo[50] = "bar";
```

This (what you effectively did) does **not** work:

```
char foo[50];
foo[50] = "bar";
```

Actually, this is wrong in several ways, not the least of which is an illegal memory access to the non-existing 51st element of `foo`...

What you need to do is reserve space for the string, either at the point of declaration...

```
char text[50];
```

...or dynamically...

```
char * text;
// ...
text = malloc( 50 );
if ( text == NULL )
{
    // error handling
}
```

...and then use `strcpy()` or similar to *copy* the string into the reserved space.

```
strcpy( text, "some message" );
```